# Decoding a slice of maps from a JSON string in Golang

Tags: json, go

Following the [Go by Example: JSON tutorial](https://gobyexample.com/json), I see how to work with a basic JSON string:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    )

type Response struct {
    Page   int      `json:"page"`
    Fruits []string `json:"fruits"`
}

func main() {
    str := `{"page": 1, "fruits": ["apple", "peach"]}`
    res := Response{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(res.Page)
    fmt.Println(res.Fruits)
}

// the output looks good here:
// 1
// [apple peach]
```

I would like to add some complexity to the `str` data object that I am decoding.

Namely, I would like to add a key with a slice of maps as its value:

```
"activities": [{"name": "running"}, {"name", "swimming"}]
```

My script now looks like below example, however, for the life of me, I can not figure out what the correct syntax is in the `Response` struct in order to get at the values in `activities`. I know that this syntax isn't correct: `Activities []string ...` but can not hack my way towards a solution that captures the data I want to display.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    )

type Response struct {
    Page   int      `json:"page"`
    Fruits []string `json:"fruits"`
    Activities []string `json:"activities"`
}

func main() {
    str := `{"page": 1, "fruits": ["apple", "peach"], "activities": [{"name": "running"}, {"name", "swimming"}]}`
    res := Response{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(res.Page)
    fmt.Println(res.Fruits)
    fmt.Println(res.Activities)
}

// the script basically craps out here and returns:
// 0
// []
// []
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use []map[string]string:

```
type Response struct {
    Page   int      `json:"page"`
    Fruits []string `json:"fruits"`
    Activities []map[string]string `json:"activities"`
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/Wd5RvK2XR9)</kbd>

Always check and handle errors. 
The example JSON has a syntax error which is corrected in the playground example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but i've recently written utility for generating exact go type from json input and in similar case you could give it a spin: https://github.com/m-zajac/json2go

For this particular example it generates from json:

```
{"page": 1, "fruits": ["apple", "peach"], "activities": [{"name": "running"}, {"name": "swimming"}]}
```

go type:

```
type Object struct {
    Activities  []struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
    }   `json:"activities"`
    Fruits  []string    `json:"fruits"`
    Page    int     `json:"page"`
}
```